# How much of the variation in X*Y is explained by the variation in X?

Tags: standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

I would like to determine what percentage of the variation in X*Y is explained by the variation in X and Y individually. In other words, is there a metric of variation for which unknown_var_metric(X*Y) = sum(unknown_var_metric(X),unknown_var_metric(Y))?

Thank you

Comment: What would you want your measure to do if $Y=1/X$ so that $XY$ is constant but $X$ and $Y$ aren't?

Comment: I see your point. Are you saying there is no way to "untangle" the interaction effect? For the sake of argument, I would think that if variation is 0 then there is no variation to explain and no contribution to variation from X or Y. If we want to treat 0 as a value, then the contribution would be equal, or 50/50.